# Is it feasible to generate a random number based on a list?

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

```
A = [8 1 5; 1 4 2; 7 5 2];

Max = 5

B = randi(Max);
```

Right now I have a part of the code which generates a random number. I am looking to generate a random number from a list of numbers, in this case the numbers listed in the first row (`8 1 5`).

Instead of using `randi` is there another function that will generate randomly one of the numbers listed in first row and also meet the `Max` criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you specified, I suggest the following:

```
A = [8 1 5; 1 4 2; 7 5 2];

% get a random number from row 1
index = randperm(length(A(1,:)));
number = A(1,index(1))

% get a randome number from row 1 that does not exceed Max
max = 5;
condition = find(A(1,:) <= max);
index = randperm(length(A(1,condition)));
number = A( 1, condition(index(1)))
```

Hope this gives some ideas,

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of the randperm function.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `arrayfun`:

```
B = arrayfun(@randi, A(1,:))
```

Comment: Thanks! Could this be easily modified to return only one number out of that row?

Comment: @JahnnyT: You mean something like `arrayfun(@randi, A(1,[2 2 2]))`?

Comment: No I am looking to output, randomly, one variable instead of three. In this case `8 1 5`. Also with the criteria that it is not over `Max = 5`. Therefore, this example the random number could be either `1 or 5`.

Comment: @JahnnyT: Ah, you mean: output either 8, 1 or 5?

Comment: Correct. And if possible less than or equal to the `Max = 5`.

Comment: @JahnnyT: Look into `randperm`. For your case: `inds = randperm(3); B = A(1,inds); B = B(1)`

Comment: Oh I missed the < 5 constraint. Well, I guess you can figure that one out -- use [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)